# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to use pip-autoremove

Tags: python, pip, windows-10, modulenotfounderror

I tried to install `pip-autoremove` and it was successfully installed. But when I tried `pip-autoremove jupyter -y` it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\pip-autoremove.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip_autoremove'
```

I tried to check system path and I see I have `C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311` and `C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts` and `C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages` available there!

Also the result for `python -m ensurepip`:

```
Looking in links: c:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp77qlwp70
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (65.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (22.3.1)
```

Moreover, `pip install --upgrade pip` couldn't help!

What is the problem?

Comment: Your error says "No module named pip_autoremove." Isn't it supposed to be pip-autoremove?

Comment: You should have checked GitHub issues first.

Answer (score 11):

This issue can be solved by moving the `pip_autoremove.py` file from its original (misplaced) location within the `Scripts` folder to the `Lib` folder within your Python program files.

More specifically, assuming you have Python 3.11.x installed, and if Python is installed for all users, then move the `pip_autoremove.py` file from:

```
C:\Program Files\Python311\Scripts
```

to

```
C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib
```

Alternatively, if Python is installed for a specific user (e.g. `Username`), then move the `pip_autoremove.py` file from:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts
```

to

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib
```

You can then run the command `pip-autoremove --version` in the command prompt and it should return `pip-autoremove 0.10.0` if everything is working correctly. From there you can remove a package and its leftover dependencies with:

```
pip-autoremove.exe some_package
```

Noting that there are the following options should you need them:

```
Options:
  -l, --list    list unused dependencies, but don't uninstall them.
  -L, --leaves  list leaves (packages which are not used by any others).
  -y, --yes     don't ask for confirmation of uninstall deletions.
```

Comment: First method you proposed worked! haven't tried the second.

Comment: @DanielTork Nice! Yeah the second is just for those users that installed the package for a specific user instead of for all users on a particular computer